# How to order by serializers.ListField on Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can I order by a `serializers.ListField` at a `ViewSet`?

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bar = serializers.ListField()
```

e.g.

I want to order by the fist element of the list

```
GET http://localhost:8000/api/foo?ordering=bar[0]

{
    ...
    results: [{bar:[1,'a']},{bar:[2,'c']},{bar:[3,'d']}]
    ...
}
```

Comment: Order In what perspective ?

Comment: e.g. `[{bar:[1,'a']},{bar:[2,'c']},{bar:[3,'d']}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override `list` method, evaluate queryset and then sort it by your key:

```
class FooViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewset):
    queryset = Foo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FooSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        order = request.query_params.get('ordering')
        q = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(q, many=True)
        sorted_q = sorted(serializer.data, key=lambda x: x['bar'][0])
        return Response(sorted_q)
```

Comment: this doesn't check what type of ordering I'm requesting in the GET request, and also is doing the ordering in the serializer instead of the viewset

Comment: @JulioMarins you don't say any word about `GET` parameters, let me think about it

Comment: @JulioMarins your problem is really weird. If you want to filter all queryset by value in that array it is to put that logic in a filter or viewset. But if you want to change representation it is best way to keep it in a serializer, because in a view you don't wan't to evaluate queryset before response. Can you explain more clear please. The final purpose is change ordering of a `bar` field in each queryset item?

Comment: it's not filtering. The problem is to order the results by the first element of `bar` which is a `serializers.ListField`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133017/discussion-between-ivan-semochkin-and-julio-marins).

Comment: With your answer I can change a single object of the results, but what I want do to is to order the results by a property of the object which is a list